Why is it 'on' rather than 'in' that precedes a TV series?
There's such a meme of 'Next Time on Dragon Ball Z' (see here):

In the anime Dragon Ball Z, the narrator poses a few questions at the end of each episode that alerts viewers as to what plot points will be addressed in the next episode.

The narrator would then say, 'next time on Dragon Ball Z'. For a video example, see here, or here.
Can I say 'next time in Dragon Ball Z'?
What if it is followed by an episode? Like, 'next time in Episode 5', is this natural? Or is it 'next time on Episode 5'?

I keep trying out phrasings in my mind, and it feels to me like "in" and "on" are largely interchangeable for events that happen in (or on) a TV show, except that "Next time on [X]" is a set phrase and sounds very strange if you try to alter it.

Personally, I would say "in Episode 5" and I associate "on" in this context with American TV shows.

"on" heads a phrase that refers to the TV series and the object of the preposition there is the name of the series.  "Next time on BBQ Pitmasters" or "Next time on Rehab Addict" is what the announcer says right before the TV audience will be shown a "teaser" for the next episode.

on a show but in an episode.

@Lambie This seems more right to me and I retract my previous comment.

I can say with confidence that "we use on with 'shows.'" We say that an actor "went on the Tonight Show to promote their movie." What counts as a show? TV shows, radio shows, podcasts... I think what counts is that it's something with "episodes" or something resembling them. Regular, self-contained installments.
Now, how did this come to be? I have no idea, but will speculate that it came along with radio (and later TV) broadcasting as we talk about "on the air."

You could say "next time on Dragon Ball Z" but that's elliptical, referring obliquely, and rather casually, to the next episode that has not aired yet. It couldn't be used to refer to the subsequent episode retrospectively, after it had aired.  For example, this would not be idiomatic:

I have been watching the series for about a month. In the first episode, the crew are stranded in the northwest passage when the sea freezes up, and next time on the show they are attacked by some kind of demonic animal. unidiomatic

With regard to your question about "next time in episode 5": since "next time on Dragon Ball Z" refers to the next episode,  "next time in episode 5" is rather like saying "in the next episode [of Dragon Ball Z] in episode 5". But the two prepositional phrases refer to the same thing, so you'd want to write "next time, in episode 5" and when saying that aloud there would be a pause at the comma, to indicate that the two prepositional phrases are standing in apposition.
Again, "next time on {series name}" in this TV series/TV episode context, can only be used when referring to the upcoming episode, the one that has not been aired yet.

I think this is completely fanciful. Apart from your good self, I find it hard to believe anyone would specifically say last week in Family Guy and next week on Family Guy, rather than the opposite way round. Both "container" and "surface" metaphoric usages are common in such contexts, with no significant US/UK usage split. It's just that in is more common.

@FumbleFingers   I don't know what you're going on about. Did I say that someone said "last week in Family Guy" anywhere in my answer or anything like it? No, I didn't. Focus, dude.   "Next week on {TV series name}" is heard very often on American TV as a segue to a "teaser" for the upcoming episode.  There's nothing fanciful about it.

You wrote It couldn't be used to refer to the subsequent episode retrospectively, after it had aired. What's that supposed to imply, if not a difference between before and after an episode has aired?

"next time" cannot be used to refer to a subsequent episode after it had aired. I added an example to the answer to show what I mean.  "next time" is not synonymous with "in the next episode" under all circumstances. It is prospective in real time.

In that case I just don't understand your answer, so I don't see how learners will make sense of it. The bottom line, like i said, is that both prepositions are commonly used in the context of next week in / on  [TV Series Name / Episode Number]. It's just that on is more common with Series Name, and in is more common with Episode Number.

@FumbleFingers I don't think you've properly understood the OP's question.   It has to do with "next time". That's central to the question.

I understand the OP to be asking whether the preposition should be in or on, for TV series and EpisodeNo within Series. Which I see @Lambie  has just addressed in a comment that I can understand.

@FumbleFingers Then answer the question as you understand it rather than accusing me of making stuff up out of whole cloth. I find your ad hominem remarks very tiresome, and they seem to occur, ironically, most often when you, a Brit, are schooling me, an American, on American English.

The last time it happened was with "Got milk?" BTW.  You were insisting that people don't say stuff like that. I cited examples of AmE ( "Got a light?"  "Got the time?" ) and you basically told me I was full of sh*t.

There's no significant US/UK usage split, as i pointed out with usage chart in my first comment. I'm not saying people don't use either preposition, simply that both are in use

And I'm sure I'll have said before that Got Milk? is an American advertising campaign on television and YouTube encouraging the consumption of milk and dairy products. When the slogan was first coined, it leveraged the "marked" usage (omitting preceding Have you, as would originally have been quite rare, otherwise they wouldn't have used it). Same as the marked construction I'm lovin' it (rather than I love it).

@FumbleFingers The advertising campaign "Got Milk? began as a billboard campaign and later moved to TV. But the question Got milk? was an everyday expression decades before that campaign ever appeared on the scene.  As I told you last time, if you and a pal went into a convenience store (these stores appeared in the 1960s) for a loaf of bread, maybe some coffee, and a box of donuts or sweet rolls of some kind, and you asked, "What else do we need?", your pal might well say "Got milk?"  I believe this is where you say to me that I don't know what I'm talking about.  You have no clue.
